# How to trigger setState in a sibling component

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently making a ToDo list and I got this input inside a child component and the array state placed inside the parent but since I'm planning on re-rendering the list depending if they are completed or not with a click, I want to move the array to its sibling component, the ToDoList component.

How do I call the `setState` that is inside the ToDoList component from its sibling, the input component?

Comment: Have a look at this from React Docs, [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to do something like:

```
const ToDoComponent = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const handleInput = (inp) => setItems([...items, inp])

    return(
    <>
        <ToDoInput handleInput = {handleInput}/>
        <ToDoList items = {items}/>
    </>);
}
```